# Cookie always is NULL in Session_Start

Tags: .net, cookies

I want in Session_Start method check if cookie with specific key exists and if not create cookie with this key.

if (Request.Cookies[key] == null)

{

SetCookie();

}

But in Session_Start it is always NULL. If check it in another place I get cookie's value.

Why is it always NULL in Session_Start?

Thanks,

kukuwka

Answer (score 1):

As David said , when you create your cookie you should set the Expires attribute:

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("UserIn");
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(100);//the cookie will disapear in 100 days.
```

I hope this will help ...

Comment: Please post your text in English please

Comment: Sorry, i just paste it before from my code, now i've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is the cookie set with an expiration date?

If not the cookie is for the session only and if you close the browser it will disappear.

Comment: Yes, I set with an expiration date. It is Null only in Session_Start.If I access to this cookie from another place I recieve the right value.